# The remote server returned an error: (412) Precondition Failed

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I see the error 412 Precondition failed with the below code. It used to work until 1st of April 2021. It started failing from 2nd April 2021.

```
var response = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.dce.com.cn");
```

Please can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seemingly dce.com.cn changed something. Perhaps they check the `User-Agent` header now. Perhaps it's something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the server. A 412 on a request with no conditional request header fields is incorrect.

Comment: Weirdly this works from the browser. Only doesn't work from c# code. I captured the request from fiddler. Tried the same request headers from c# as well. Still seeing the same 412 error.

Comment: https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dce.com.cn shows the 412 as well.

Comment: *** Fiddler Request ***  POST http://www.dce.com.cn/publicweb/quotesdata/dayQuotesEn.html HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 69
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Comment: Different HTTP method, different URI.

Comment: Yes @Julian-Reschke. The actual URI we use is in the fiddler request. To make it simple initially I provided the base URI.

Comment: Hi @Julian-Reschke - You are right. It's a restriction on the server. I wrote an email as well to DCE. They confirmed that they stopped the automation tools reaching their website. Thanks. I accepted the answer.